# Problems with do.call rbind

Tags: r, rbind

I have the following F1 (F1.txt):

```
"sequence" "support"
"1" "<{EADFE20F543836047330DEFFB893127AF536560121698ADE2FCE6985E07A40D8 SELECT;DD2E595CF23E65E128560B655E0C6848 SELECT}>" 0.286903266331658
"2" "<{F73431225ED64969DC4BEBD06092FD6F SELECT}>" 0.121309673366834
"3" "<{88FFF14FDD46ED862DAEB36F8D0F6215 SELECT}>" 0.0820508793969849
```

and additional file (F2.txt):

```
"sequence" "support"
"1" "<{6A5167FBE316A83E1AB22FB3371D2E48 CREATE TEMP TABLE}>" 0.0808225046408682
"2" "<{6A5167FBE316A83E1AB22FB3371D2E48 SELECT}>" 0.0808225046408682
"3" "<{6A5167FBE316A83E1AB22FB3371D2E48 INSERT}>" 0.0808225046408682
```

I read each of them by using the following commands:

```
F1 <-read.table (file.choose(), header = FALSE,sep = ",")
F2 <-read.table (file.choose(), header = FALSE,sep = ",")
```

and then used:

```
FF <- do.call(rbind,list(F1,F2))
```

I get FF like as:

```
> head (FF)
                                                                                                                                                V1
1                                                                                                                                 sequence support
2          1 <{EADFE20F543836047330DEFFB893127AF536560121698ADE2FCE6985E07A40D8 SELECT;DD2E595CF23E65E128560B655E0C6848 SELECT}> 0.286903266331658
3                                                                                  2 <{F73431225ED64969DC4BEBD06092FD6F SELECT}> 0.121309673366834
```

Where did V1 come from?

Comment: Why did you do `sep = ","` when it's really not?

Comment: Add `header = T` to your `read.table`. V1, V2, V3,... are the default column names assigned if there are no column names. If you look, they're present in F1 and F2 before you get to the `rbind`. And, as pointed out above, get rid of `sep = ","`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the commenters:
The read.table should be:

```
F1 <-read.table (file.choose(), header = TRUE)
F2 <-read.table (file.choose(), header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Probably better would be to not specify `sep` at all, just in case the single space is inconsistent. Read the documenation at `?read.table` to see the (very nice) default behavior for `sep`.